# Timing methods in Java produces incorrect values?

Tags: java

I tried outputting the average time it takes to run a particular method using `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
            int n = (int) Math.pow(2, i);
            double total_time = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                runMethod();
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                double difference = (double) (endTime - startTime);
                total_time += difference / 1000;

            }
            System.out.println("N = " + Integer.toString(n) +": " + Double.toString(total_time / 5) + " s");
        }
```

However, I tried timing this myself between reported times in standard output but it seems to be way off (for one iteration, I timed it to be around 30 seconds but it reported 8). Is this the wrong method to use? Or am I implementing it incorrectly?

Is it possible that the standard output is delayed, such that the actual time is not reported until well after the method has finished, so that I would myself calculate a longer time based on what is shown in the output?

Comment: You never assign to `endTime` in this code.

Comment: Also, don't convert to double until after you have summed all the differences. Do you really need fractions anyway? Work with longs, which are precise, do the division only in the end. And remember this is *not* how you run a benchmark in Java.

Comment: `System.nanoTime` is better for this than `System.currentTimeMillis` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--

Comment: My apologies, I edited the code to include `endTime`. I had this in my code I just didn't copy and paste properly.

Roughly speaking, however, can I trust what the output says based on this code? I don't care about extreme precision, I just want a relatively rough estimate in seconds. The difference between what I time and what is reported seems too large to blame deviation for anything else?

Comment: Looking at your specific issue: _I timed it to be around 30 seconds but it reported 8_. Yes that is a large difference. Is it as simple as the fact that your `N =...` statistics are reporting average times - and you have to multiply each average by the number of iterations, to get overall (wall clock) time? It depends on what you mean by "I timed it" and "it reported" of course. Can we at least rule that out as the cause of your discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

As others have observed:
- don't cast to `double` until you need to
- use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`

This is what it could look like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {

    final int  n          = 1 << i; // = 2**i
    /**/  long total_time = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        final long t0 =  System.nanoTime();
        runMethod();
        total_time   += (System.nanoTime() - t0);
    }
    System.out.println("N = " + n + ": " + ((double)total_time / 1_000 / 1_000 / 1_000 / 5) + " s");
    System.out.println("N = " + n + ": " + ((double)total_time / 1_000 / 1_000         / 5) + " ms");
    System.out.println("N = " + n + ": " + ((double)total_time / 1_000                 / 5) + " μs");
    System.out.println("N = " + n + ": " + ((double)total_time                         / 5) + " ns");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the underscore literal is unnecessary? It doesn't seem supported on the JDK version I'm using.

Comment: No, the underscore is purely to aid readability. Instead of 1_000 / 1_000 / 1_000 you could write 1_000_000_000

Comment: Ok. Is it still possible that the standard output doesn't match what I time? It still seems off, but I wonder if that is just because of process control and switching processes before reporting the final time instead of the actual timing being off.

Comment: It may depend on what runMethod() does, but unless its some multi-threaded client-server function, it should give you a fair value, but as @Carcigenicate indicated, Benchmarks are quite tricky. You really need to compare 2 blocks of code: one with everything except what you're trying to measure, and one with it. The whole lot needs to be repeated many, many times. That way you can factor out the code you're using to do the measurement & get very accurate results.

Comment: The method I am testing is multithreaded, but I believe in the method it utilizes the `thread.join()` method to wait for the threads to complete before returning and continuing. This shouldn't be a problem then right?

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  runMethod();
  long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Sorry, changed to include this.